# Deploy Only Single Non-exported Function in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, command-line, google-cloud-functions

I have created the following function in my the file of my firebase cloud functions:

```
function whatsMyName(name) {
  return "your name is " + name
}
```

When I run the following in the command line, then the function *is* deployed:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

But, this deploys *all* of my functions.  I would like to only deploy the `whatsMyName` function.  Typically, if I have a function that is exported, like so:

```
exports.someExportedFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   // do some stuff
}
```

Then I can run the following to deploy the exported function:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:someExportedFunction
```

However, when I run the following, the non-exported function is not deployed:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:whatsMyName
```

**Does anyone understand why this doesn't individually deploy my non-exported function, `whatsMyName`, and how to deploy a non-exported function for Firebase Cloud Functions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLI can only individually deploy *exported function triggers*.  It can *not* specifically deploy any arbitrary JavaScript named function.

In other words, what you're trying to do is not currently possible.

Comment: any plan to add this functionality?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  You can always file a feature request.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please accept it as correct.