# How to organize multiple Cloud Function in Firebase with JS to avoid deploy issues

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase

I have an app based on Flutter and Firebase. Started as a sort of a “auto-challenge” after a Flutter course, it is now in production with some thousand of users.
I use Firebase Cloud Functions, and as I think is pretty typical I started to write one by one my CFs in my index.js file.
Now I have about 6k lines of code there, with ~100CF.

Everything works as expected, but I would like to organize them in a more intelligent way, in particular to avoid pain during function deploy.

Let’s say I have 2 functions:

1. `exports.checkNewUser = functions.firestore.document('Users/{user}').onCreate(`
2. `exports.userHasReachedPrize = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {`

Both this functions inside need for example to retrieve `UserDisplayName`, and so I wrote a simple JS function:
`async function getUserDisplayName(userId) {….}`

My current problem is that if I make an even small change to `getUserDisplayName`, being this function outside o the scope of the “exported” ones, to deploy it I have to deploy the WHOLE project’s functions (`firebase deploy --only function`).
And since exported functions are not 2 but ~100, I pretty often obtain `⚠  functions: got "Quota Exceeded" error while trying to update projects`.

So, which is the best way to handle a situation like this? In particular: how can I organize files in order to deploy changes to auxiliary “utility” functions (not exported) without needing to deploy everything?

I’ve read the official documentation on “how to organize multiple functions” (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions?gen=1st), but this division in groups does not seem to help with the problem of not-exported functions

I found some other questions here on SO, but they seem not to give solutions ([Deploy Only Single Non-exported Function in Firebase Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863445/deploy-only-single-non-exported-function-in-firebase-cloud-functions))

Answer (score 0):

> how can I organize files in order to deploy changes to auxiliary “utility” functions (not exported) without needing to deploy everything?

You can't.  Each function exists entirely independently from all other functions.  There isn't any sort of "common" space where you can update shared code without deploying a function that uses it.

Internally, Cloud Functions works by creating a server "image" that contains everything needed for the function to operate.  This includes all code and all configuration files.  Once this image is deployed, it can only be changed by redeploying the function.

So, if you want to update the way a function works in any way, you must redeploy it.